# Python3 - Requests with Sock5 proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests, tor

Is there a way to use sock5 proxy to use TOR with requests? I know that requests only use http proxy...

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com',proxies= my_proxy)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `socks, socket` modules

```
import socks
import socket
from urllib import request

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
r = request.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com')
print(r.read()) # check ips
```

The `socks` package can be installed from multiple packages which are forks of [socksipy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/). One particular one that also works on Python3 is [PySocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks). You can install it, for example, with pip:

```
pip3 install PySocks
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me on windows. I don't understand why. Do you have an idean on what I should investigate ?

Comment: raise GeneralProxyError("Connection closed unexpectedly")

Answer (score 2):

I think at the moment `requests` works with socks5 out of the box.

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com'
proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
           'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: It needs `pip install "requests[socks]"` too.