# Python 3 Specifying Socks5 Proxy In Specified Request Only

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777692/python3-requests-with-sock5-proxy) states how to use a Socks5 proxy in Python 3. Unfortunately this answer wouldn't work when one wants to send requests over the socks proxy and not over the proxy at virtually the same time.

I want to be able to do this where the first request uses the proxy and the second uses my IP at virtually the same time without having to switch the sockets around:

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests
threadPoolTasks1=[]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:     

    #this request should use the proxy. I should see the IP reflecting that    
    threadPoolTasks1.append(executor.submit(print(requests.get("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/").text)))

    #this request won't use the proxy. 
    threadPoolTasks1.append(executor.submit(print(requests.get("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/").text)))
```